# Total energy in tight binding methods

Tags: material-science, simulations, tight-binding

How to calculate total energy in tight binding methods?

The total energy is calculated as the sum of the eigenvalues of the occupied state?

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to multiply each eigenvalue by the corresponding occupation number if there's degeneracy.